# How do I fix the scrollbar to always be at the bottom using tailwind css?

Tags: css, django, templates, tailwind-css

I have the following div with a list of divs. These child divs are going to be a message boxes of a chat box.

```
<div class="scroll" id="display">

</div>
```

However, obviously I need the scoller to be at the bottom automatically whenever the user enters the page, because I want to show the latest conversation first. How am I able to do that? Thank you, and please leave any comments below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**Try this :**

```
const chatBox = document.getElementById('chatBox');

// Function to scroll the chat box to the bottom
function scrollToBottom() {
chatBox.scrollTop = chatBox.scrollHeight;
}

window.onload = scrollToBottom;


<div class="overflow-auto" id="chatBox">

</div>
```

**If you want to only use Tailwind CSS you can try this :**

```
<div class="overflow-auto h-96 scroll-snap-y-container">
<!-- Empty element to push content down -->
<div class="flex h-0 w-0">.</div>

<!-- Your chat message divs will be appended here -->

<!-- Empty element to create space at the bottom -->
<div class="flex h-0 w-0">.</div>
</div>
```

**Note :** `You can adjust the h-96 class to control the height of your chat box.`

Comment: I can't seem to make it work. Can you recheck your code again?

Comment: which code you try ? JS or only tailwind ?

Comment: I tried both. I also tried placing the scripts above and below the div section

Comment: Can you please add more code snippits to understand better.

Comment: There really isn't much to add, because that is basically all of my code. I guess I have my width and height set in the div as well, but that is not that important. Can you add a snippet that shows that your code actually works?

Comment: Check the edited answer i add the gif file with working code.

Comment: above code solve your problem ?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve the problem. I had to tweak some code for my case, but your code works for most people with this issue.